# Can't get the Exchange 2007 Receive Connectors Logging to work

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, logging, log-files, email-server

I have been able to setup the Send Connector Logging and it works as expected, but I'm not getting any logging from the Receive Connectors. I have tried enabling via the EMC as well as via powershell and have even tried writing the logs to different locations with no success. They are seemingly not being written at all anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot did it! Not something I can take down whenever. :)

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't seeing any protocol logging written then its possible you're not generating any SMTP traffic to the Receive Connector.

How are you testing this?

Keep in mind that email between two mailboxes on your Exchange server, even though it traverses the Hub Transport server, doesn't use the Receive Connector to do so and so it won't generate protocol logging.

Comment: The receive connector that I'm concerned with, I absolutely know is generating traffic. This one is called "Accepted Mail Relay" and I have it limited to specific IP addresses. When people add say a printer and they test it w/o me adding it to this list it doesn't go through, but after I add the IP of the new printer as accepted it does.